# show that d is a distance on X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am having trouble with this Analysis 1 problem about showing that d is a valid distance function on X.

> let ( $\Gamma$, $dist_{\Gamma}$) be a metric space. Let $X$ be a set. Let $f: X \rightarrow \Gamma$ be injective. Define $d : X\times X \rightarrow R$ by $d(x, z) = dist_{\Gamma}( f(x), f(y)) \quad   \textrm{for every x, z in X}$

show that function d is a distance on $X$.
I do not really know how to prove this but I am going to show you my thought process:

first of all we are given that $\Gamma$ is a set and that $f$ is injective: by definition injective means that for every x (in X in this case) there is a different $y\in Y$ (R in this case). If $d(x, z) = dist_{\Gamma}( f(x), f(y)) \quad   \textrm{for every x, z in X}$ then we know that $f(x)$ and $f(z)$ are in $\Gamma$ by hypothesis, then $dist_{\Gamma}( f(x), f(y))$ is a distance function on $\Gamma$: 1)distance(a, a) = 0 in this case it is true as f is injective. 2) distance(x,z) = 0 iff x = z, same reason. I would prove the last three properties just by saying that $dist_{\Gamma}$ is a distance on $\Gamma$ and $f(x)$ and $f(z)$ are in $\Gamma$ therefore they must hold. However so far I could say all of this in relation to $\Gamma$ but I could not figure out how to deal with $R$ and prove that $d$ is a distance on $X$. I would be deeply grateful for any help or tip ^_^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y\in X$, then$$d(x,y)=\operatorname{dist}_\Gamma\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr)=\operatorname{dist}_\Gamma\bigl(f(y),f(x)\bigr)=d(y,x).$$And if $x,y,z\in X$, then\begin{align}d(x,z)&=\operatorname{dist}_\Gamma\bigl(f(x),f(z)\bigr)\\&\leqslant\operatorname{dist}_\Gamma\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr)+\operatorname{dist}_\Gamma\bigl(f(y),f(z)\bigr)\\&=d(x,y)+d(y,z).\end{align}